# Auto expand div's width

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this fiddle that I found, and resize the result window: http://jsfiddle.net/qPHgR/286/

Here's the css from the fiddle:

```
.left { 
    float: left;
}
.right { 
    background-color: #DDD;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I want to achieve the same thing, but I want the right div to have a fixed width (300px) and the left div to expand/contract when the window is resized. I can not figure out how to fix it without changing the HTML order of left and right div in the code. I've experimentet with floats and other attirbutes but can't make it work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your own code?

Comment: @yentup I experimented earlier but could not figure out how to fix it. I dont have any code.

Comment: How did you experiment without code?

Comment: @yentup I didn't save anything  since I could not figure it out^^

Comment: Then go try again and if your code doesn't work, post it.

Comment: @yentup This is what I came up with http://jsfiddle.net/qPHgR/287/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qPHgR/298/)**

The floats are important for keeping the two elements next to each other. I added 310 pixels of margin to the right of the left `DIV` (300 pixels for the right `DIV`, and 10 pixels as white space). I then used a negative `margin-left` to pull the right `DIV` over on top of that margin.

I also added `overflow: hidden;` on `DIV.container` to illustrate a simple float containment solution. This can be removed if unnecessary, but you may find it makes the remainder of your layout styling easier.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:
http://jsfiddle.net/7DKX8/2

```
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: #DDD; } 

 .right {

     width: 300px;
     overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: I want .left and .right to be next to each other. The wrapper width should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.left { 
  background-color: #DDD;
  margin-right: 300px;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: `position: absolute;` removes the `DIV` on the right from the document flow, which could be problematic if the text on the right is longer than the text on the left (it will appear over any other elements further down the document).

Answer (score 0):

Is this sort of what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/3ZUas/

The text interferes, but is this what you were going for?

Main thing is `float: right;`

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        some text goes here which is just here to change
    </div>    
    <div class="right">
        some longer bunch of text to go here, it should stick to the right some longer bunch of text to go here, it should stick to the rightsome longer bunch of text to go here, it should stick to the rightsome longer bunch of text to go here, it should stick to the rightsome longer bunch of text to go here, it should stick to the rightsome longer bunch of text to go here, it should stick to the right
    </div>
</div>
```

​CSS:

```
.left { 
    float: left;
margin-right: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.right { 
position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    overflow: hidden;

}
​
```

Hope this works for you...!